# How to disable initial hover transition on mount in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, animation

Imagine a picture that is being zoomed in when hovered and zoomed out when not hovered. In case the cursor happens to be inside the picture when it is mounted, zoom transition plays.

React:

```
...

{ visible ? 
    <IconVisible 
      className="icon"
      onClick={handleOnClick}
    />
  :
    <IconMasked 
      className="icon"
      onClick={handleOnClick}
    />
}

...
```

CSS:

```
.icon {
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(1)
}

.icon:hover {
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(1.5)
}
```

Check out [**the demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mount-initial-hover-problem-702nr)

How to disable such initial transition? In the demo the icon should not shrink and expand after being clicked.

One way to do this is to create a special class that is the same as zoomed in version (same as .icon:hover) and add this class initially and then remove this class in useEffect. 
The drawback is that it requires two renders, is messy and overcomplicated. Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Have you tried using `unset`, perhaps with `!important` as the attribute value? I know it's not best practice, but without modifying the core files, it could be your work around. For example: `transform: unset !important;`

Comment: @dmanexe you mean to add it in the initial class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you needed to zoom in when you enter the mouse inside the icon, but when click the icon also showing unexpected animation( zoom out then zoom in).
The reason is to React:

1) when a Visible is true then show the first icon otherwise 2nd icon
2) In React DOM first time render icon and change the icon this Rendered and it's a new icon so animation repeated.

Solutions:
1) you create a wrapper for this icon
2) implement animation in the wrapper

you can following the code here

```
<div className="icon">
    {visible ? (
      <IconVisible onClick={handleOnClick} />
    ) : (
      <IconMasked onClick={handleOnClick} />
    )}
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.icon {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 100px;
  font-size: 80px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.icon:hover {
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

you can also follow the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mount-initial-hover-problem-eds9g

**Thank you**